# How to automate generators?

Tags: astroneer

I have a **generator** that generates (*no way*) energy from **Organic** placed on it. Is there any way to automate this process?

Maybe using a **storage unit** where you place a generator and organic?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to automate it, but if you have organic in your backpack you can place it by clicking the "ghost" resource on an empty generator.

Comment: FWIW according to last week's livestream, an automation update is in the works.

Answer (score 2):

The game currently has no major automation system, though one is planned down the road. However, you can automate generators to some degree. If you have an empty small or medium generator (it may need to be turned on) it will automatically pull in whichever resource it uses (either organic or coal depending on size). I believe this works with storage units. I know it works on rovers. Using this, you can fil up a platform with organics or coal and then add a generator to it to use the fuel. The new Extra-Large Platform may work well for this.